# Poblemas Ventana Diseño WindowsForms.NetFrameWork

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

es comento mi problema para ver si me pueden dar una mano.

Estoy elaborando un proyecto personal en Visual Studio 2019 (C#). Para evitar la redundancia de métodos en ciertos botones comunes en varios formularios me veo en la necesidad de realizar una herencia de un FormBase a FormUsuarios.

El problema es que cuando declaro la referencia VentanasUsuarios: FormBase o VentanasUsuarios: DogeFacts.FormBase me sale el siguiente error en en diseñador de VentanasUsuarios: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

He revisado si tengo algún problema marcado en el .Designer pero no veo problemas ahí.

Cuando ejecuto el programa e ingreso a ese formulario en específico observo que el boton que quiero heredar esta puesto en el FormUsuarios o sea la herencia la realiza pero me esta bloqueando la edición del formulario y no se por qué. La idea del ForBase es crear botones los cuales pueda reutilizar en otros formularios y evitar redundancia de codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DogeFact
{
    public partial class FormBase : Form
    {
        public FormBase()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormBase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using Recursos;

namespace DogeFact
{
    public partial class VentanasUsuario : FormBase
    {
        public VentanasUsuario()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void VentanasUsuario_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void VentanasUsuario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Cmd creara una consulta a la base de datos con la informacion de LoginForm.Codigo
            string cmd = "Select * From Usuarios Where id_user=" + LoginForm.codigo;
            DataSet DS = Connection.Ejecutar(cmd);
            label4.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name_user"].ToString();
            label5.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id_user"].ToString();
            label6.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["account"].ToString();

            string url = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["foto"].ToString();
            imgUs.Image = Image.FromFile(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Mostra el constructor de tu clase base, el problema esta ahi, muy probablemente llames a algo que no existe... Tene en cuenta que aunque sea en tiempo de diseño, algunas cosas se ejecutan igual! Y es muy probable que no necesites heredar.. no se que tratas de hacer, pero si se repite la funcionalidad no seria mejor aplicar un patron mvvm?? sobre todo si trabajas en wpf...

Comment: Seria bueno que tu pregunta la completes con la [pila de llamadas/call stack](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019) para poder ver cual es el objeto que no tienes instancia. Como te comentan se ejecuta en modo diseño para presentar, y seguramente falta alguna referencia de instancia

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias por el consejo ya realize los cambios que me mandaron a la pregunta y agregue parte del codigo donde estoy teniendo el error, si hay algo mas que pueda aclarar notificarmelo. Estoy trabajando con herencias por que hay ciertos botones que necesito que estén en 3 a 4 formularios como el boton salir, o generar reporte ya que es un proyecto con control de usuarios que da permisos distintos dependiendo del nivel pero hay ciertas acciones que todos pueden realizar.

Comment: Todo lo que esta en ese load del form, suena raro.. que es LoginForm.codigo???y si tenes componentes comunes, tal vez deberias usar usercontrols (pero no niego que heredar puede ser tu mejor solucion, habria que ver el proyecto completo)

Comment: ¿La referencia se la has cambiado directamente en el código? Si es así ha entrado en conflicto la definición del código con la que tiene el designer. Retorna tu código a la versión inicial de modo tal que puedas ver la ventana del diseñador  y a través de las propiedades del diseñador lo cambias. Lo otro es que hagas los cambios en el código y en el código del Designer manualmente.

Comment: Ah, porque lo tienes que hacer así es porque en el código el designer le agrega las inicialización y creación del formulario y sus controles. Es aparte está oculta por eso no la ves a simple vista. Para verla debes de activarla. Es donde está el InitializeComponent()

Comment: Por último, la herencia no se está realizando. El botón se muestra porque ya estaba  definido en tu formulario no es que la clase padre cree los controles. Porque el inicializar se ejecuta en el que está la ckase y se llama dos veces